# How to shorten S3\Paperclip URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

We are trying to fit link to video in Twitter feed and even with short DNS, it needs to be shorter:

http://domain.com/videos/164/original.mp4

I guess you could change the paperclip attachment name from videos to just v and buy a few chars but has anyone came up with a better way to shorten S3\Paperclip style links in Rails?

It doesn't seem to be anything you can do in routes as it's at S3 at this point.

Any good idea appreciated.

Comment: Your link will be shortened using Twitter's t.co shortener regardless what your URL is, per https://support.twitter.com/articles/78124-posting-links-in-a-tweet

Comment: Yes, we want to use in a few different places though, email, etc,. Would like to figure out a rails solution.

Answer (score 2):

I use the bitly gem at https://github.com/philnash/bitly

super easy to configure and use!

Add to gem file

```
gem 'bitly'
```

run bundler

```
bundle
```

create an account at [https://bitly.com/][1]

create config/initializers/bitly.rb and add the configuration info

```
Bitly.configure do |config|
  config.api_version = 3
  config.login = "Bitly_Username"   # <--- from the account you created above
  config.api_key = "API_KEY"        # <--- from the account you created above
end
```

restart your rails app and start using the gem as follow

```
bitlink = Bitly.client
bitlink = bitly.shorten("http://www.howtomovetomaui.com/blogs/super_long_link_page_history_one/this_will_never_stop/ET-want-to-go-home.html", :history => 1)
```

I use it in my model to update twitter from my site so I have a after_save call as follow

```
after_save :update_twitter, :on => :new

def update_twitter
  // code goes here
end
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot, I juste needed to change config.api_key to config.access_token

Answer (score 0):

You might try the 'shortly' gem.  It supports quite a few different url shortening services.

- https://rubygems.org/gems/shortly
- https://github.com/bagwanpankaj/shortly